# LdapBundle (Boris Mroel) with multiples providers (Db and LDAP), only take DB provider

Tags: php, symfony, ldap, bundle

I have a problem with using LdapBundle with both authentication database and ldap.

I've try to do it like this :

My security.yml

```
security:
encoders:
    IMAG\LdapBundle\User\LdapUser:  plaintext
    Sermeta\HomeBundle\Entity\User: 
        algorithm:        sha1
        encode_as_base64: false
        iterations:       1

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

providers:
    multiples:
        chain:
            providers: [administrators, ldap]
    ldap:
        id: imag_ldap.security.user.provider

    administrators:
        entity: { class: "SermetaHomeBundle:User", property: username }

firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    login_firewall:
        pattern:    ^/login$
        anonymous:  ~    
        imag_ldap:
            check_path: login_check
            login_path: login
            provider: multiples
        logout:
            path:           /logout
            target:         /home

    secured_area:
        pattern:    ^/
        imag_ldap:
            provider: multiples
        imag_ldap:
            check_path: login_check
            login_path: login
            provider: multiples
        logout:
            path:   /logout
            target: /home



access_control:
    - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }

imag_ldap:
    client:
        host: myipadress
        port: 389
        skip_roles: true
        bind_username_before: true
user:
    base_dn: dc=mydc,dc=fr
    name_attribute: uid
```

But when I test this, I can log user with the database password, but when I try with ldap password I've an "Bad Credential" error. (Seems logic if it check only database :/)

According to bundle documentation I put `"bind_username_before: true"` but it doesn't seem to check it.

(I need database authentication to get user roles (when I will finish with this @!* authentication ...))

Comment: Are you able to log in user only with LDAP user provider (without db)? If not, are there any log messages in symfony log (logs/dev.log)?

Comment: You're right. I've tried with only ldap authentication and I have :[2015-03-23 15:59:10] ldap_connection.ERROR: LDAP returned an error with code 1 : Operations error [] []
I've another site just with PHP (No framework), and with the same host ip and dc I have no problem to connect.

Comment: You have to play with LDAP configuration and getting connection to work

Comment: The same connection works with a basic PHP code. Do ldapbundle must have an admin account to work ?

Comment: So I did my own SecurityBundle, Now I have exactly what I need, and ldap connection works perfectly. Thx for your help